# Use of Optimization Algorithms for finding shortest path in network

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

I am new to the subject of algorithm design and graph theory. I am simulating large content based network consisting of thousands of routers. I am using "Learning by reverse path" for routing. Requested content names and contents are propagated in network using flooding. Routers check for matching names in routing tables and either reply back or populate routing table with unmatched requested content name and contents. Will using optimization algorithm like Ant colony optimization, hill climbing etc instead of learning by reverse path improve routing efficiency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your graph satisfy the triangle inequality i.e. is an euklidian space then I suggest you to use the christofides approximation algorithm because it has a guarantee to be 3/2 in the optimum. Other heuristic algorithm like ant colony optimization are very fast and efficient but not very safe. A good example for an ant colony optimization (and brute force and dp solution) is the google map tsp solver in javascript. I believe a space-filling-curve is a good approximation too and has a certain guarantee. You may look into a z-curve or a hilbert curve. You can find a good article about the hilbert curve at Nick spatial index quadtree hilbert curve blog or in the book Hacker's delight. I suggest to look into constructing of monotonic n-ary gray codes and hamiltonian path either.

Comment: Thanks a-lot for detailed reply. Can you please point me to some introductory book on the subject of space filling curves.